# Parsin SoapObject without knowing the tags in it

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-ksoap2

Webservice returns me a soapobject xml string how can i parse it into an arrayList without knowing the tag in it.Is that a tool ol library out there ? i know question is so typical but i'm new in android and webservice things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a parser like DOM Parser/Builder (out of the box support); you will find a method called getChildNodes() which will retrieve all the children from the root node. You can store them in an array and then process each of these appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer im gonna try it.